# How to fix 'compileTestJava error: cannot find symbol' by using gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, gradle, automated-tests

I want to start some test cases by using gradle.
As soon as I start the following command via terminal: 
**gradle clean chromeTest -Durl="https://www.hh.de"**

Then I get the following error message at the **:compileTestJava** step immediately :

```
/home/jawar/git/seleniumHH/src/test/java/content/Tina_Tickets.java:9: 
error: cannot find symbol
import org.testng.Assert;
                 ^
symbol:   class Assert
location: package org.testng.annotations

/home/jawar/git/seleniumHH/src/test/java/content/Tina_Tickets.java:10: 
error: cannot find symbol
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
                             ^
symbol:   class AfterTest
location: package org.testng.annotations

/home/jawar/git/seleniumHH/src/test/java/content/Tina_Tickets.java:11: 
error: cannot find symbol
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
                             ^
symbol:   class BeforeTest
location: package org.testng.annotations

/home/jawar/git/seleniumHH/src/test/java/content/Tina_Tickets.java:12: 
error: cannot find symbol
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
                             ^
symbol:   class Parameters
location: package org.testng.annotations

/home/jawar/git/seleniumHH/src/test/java/content/Tina_Tickets.java:13: 
error: cannot find symbol
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
                             ^
symbol:   class Test
location: package org.testng.annotations
```

My test classes are saved in path: **src/test/java**

This is my test class with TestNG annotations which I'm trying to execute with gradle:

```
package content;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import de.hamburg.HHTest;
import de.hamburg.browser.Chrome;
import de.hamburg.browser.Firefox;

public class Tina_Tickets extends HHTest {
    @Parameters({ "platform", "browser", "version" })
    @BeforeTest(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setup(String platform, String browser, String version) throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setPlatform(org.openqa.selenium.Platform.WIN10);
        System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4stack", "true");
        caps.setCapability("SeleniumTests", "redhat5 && amd64");

        String url = System.getProperty("url");
        Assert.assertNotNull(url, "Url sollte nicht null sein");
        System.err.println("URL =" + url);
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("url"));

        if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {

            driver = Firefox.initFirefox(url, driver);
            driver.navigate().to(url + "/tina-turner-musical/");

        } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {

            driver = Chrome.initChrome(url, driver);
            driver.navigate().to(url + "/tina-turner-musical/");
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The Browser Type is undefined");
        }
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void afterTest() {
        driver.quit();

    }

    /**
     * 
     * @throws InterruptedException
     */
    @Test(description = "Calculating Test")
    public void checkTickets() throws InterruptedException {

        if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html//span[@id='articleText']//button[.='Tickets buchen']")).isDisplayed()) {
            RanorexWaitXpath("/html//span[@id='articleText']//button[.='Tickets & Hotel buchen']");
            RanorexWaitXpath("//span[@id='articleText']//div[@class='slideshow-container']");
            RanorexWaitXpath("/html//span[@id='articleText']//div[@class='links-n-buy']");

            RanorexXpathClick("/html//span[@id='articleText']//button[.='Tickets buchen']");
            ArrayList<String> tabs2 = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
            driver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(1));
            String url1 = driver.getCurrentUrl();
            System.out.println(url1);
            driver.close();
            driver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(0));

            RanorexWaitXpath("/html//span[@id='articleText']//button[.='Tickets & Hotel buchen']");
            RanorexXpathClick("/html//span[@id='articleText']//button[.='Tickets & Hotel buchen']");

            RanorexWaitXpath("//div[@id='main']/div");
            String url2 = driver.getCurrentUrl();
            System.out.println(url2);

        }
    }
}
```

And this is my build.gradle script:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'


jar {
    version  '1.0'
    baseName 'SeleniumStarter'
    extension '.jar'
}

description = "Gradle Selenium WebDriver"
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}



repositories {

    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal() 
}

ext.seleniumVersion = '3.12.0'

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version:seleniumVersion
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-server', version:seleniumVersion
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-edge-driver', version:seleniumVersion
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-firefox-driver', version:seleniumVersion
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-chrome-driver', version:seleniumVersion
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-api', version:seleniumVersion
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version:seleniumVersion

    compile group: 'org.uncommons', name: 'reportng', version:'1.1.4'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version:'4.12'
    testCompile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version:'6.11'
}


task chromeTest (type: Test) {
    useTestNG() {
    suites 'src/test/resources/hhde.xml'
    }
    systemProperties(System.getProperties())
        println System.properties['url']
        testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}

eclipse {
  classpath {
  containers 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.classpathcontainer'}
}

// A custom task to show report on tests that have run
task viewResults(dependsOn: ['seleniumTest','contentTest'] , type:Exec) {
        workingDir './build/reports/tests'      
        commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'start index.html' 
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.10' //we want gradle 2.10 to run this project
}

task logInfo (dependsOn: ['seleniumTest','contentTest']){
    logging.captureStandardOutput LogLevel.INFO
    doLast {

        println 'test'
        println System.properties['url']
        println 'url'

    }

task printProps {
    doLast {
        println commandLineProjectProp
        println gradlePropertiesProp
        println systemProjectProp
        println envProjectProp
        println System.properties['system']

        }
    }
}
```

I would be really glad for any help.

Comment: @Krishnan Mahadevan Are you sure that this issue hasn't got anything to do with TestNG?

Comment: Yes. Pretty sure. What you are seeing is due to a messed up CLASSPATH. TestNG has got nothing to do with that.